# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined ' in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my react-native project,

i installed follwing

```
npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack
```

after edit my 'app.js' file like below,

```js
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack'


import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from './screens/RegisterScreen'

const AppStack=createStackNavigator({
  Home:HomeScreen
});

const AuthStack=createStackNavigator({
  Login:LoginScreen
});

export default createAppContainer((
  {
    Loading:LoadingScreen,
    App:AppStack,
   Auth:AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName:"Loading"
  }
));
```

HomeScreen, LoadingScreen, LoginScreen, RegisterScreen are I created classes extend by 'React.Component'

when i run the project, it gives follwing run time error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStateForAction' of undefined
```

[image]

How I solve this run time error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the stacks directly inside the container,You can use a single stack or use the switch navigator that you have imported like below

```
const switchNav=createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(switchNav);
```